# How to adjust the alignment of placeholder text in input box?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

[image]

The placeholder text in the third box appears in the middle while i want to be at the top.
**HTML**

```
<div id="message">
    <ul>
      <li><h1>Send us a message</h1></li>
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="Email"></li>
      <li><input type="text" style="height:150px;" placeholder="Message"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Send</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzaL2/)**

Comment: maybe you should use `textarea` instead of `input type="text"` for your message?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're wanting a multi-line input field you should use the `textarea` element.

```
<li>
    <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</li>
```

You can then style this however you like using the `textarea` selector:

```css
#message input,
#message textarea {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#message li input[type=text],
#message li textarea {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

#message li textarea {
    height: 150px;
    resize: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/ZzaL2/3/).

Answer (score 3):

To style placeholder text, you'll need vendor prefix CSS properties.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

[Read this document](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

**Updated:**

In your case you use input box instead of using text-area. So if you want to move your text on top `use a text-area instead of using input`.

Comment: How will this align placeholder to top?

Comment: No, it's not move text on top because OP used input box instead of using textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align:center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align:center; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
 <li><input type="text" style="height:150px;" placeholder="Message"></li>
```

use:

```
<li><textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Message"></textarea> </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

**you can do this in a easy way by using `vertical-align:text-top;`**

```
<li><textarea style="vertical-align:text-top" placeholder="Message"></textarea> </li>
```